# How to use log4net with Nunit?

Tags: c#

I have a DLL class that create `log4net` log:

```
[SetUpFixture]
public class Application
{
    private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);


[SetUp]
    private Application()
    {
        log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure();
        ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Application));
        log.Debug("This is a debug message");
        log.Warn("This is a warn message");
    }
}
```

and `Log4Net.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821" />
  </configSections>

  <!-- Log4net Logging Setup -->
  <log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender,log4net">
      <file value="c:\\mylogfile.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="INFO" />
        <levelMax value="FATAL" />
      </filter>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

My program starts the `nunit.exe` by:

```
 string nunitAppPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.4\bin\nunit.exe";
            Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(nunitAppPath));
```

and have a reference to DLL.

I have a text file in c name :`mylogfile.txt`, but it's always null.

Comment: What are you trying to test? also make sure `Copy Always` or `Copy If Newer` is selected for your `log4net.config` file.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do. Are you trying to log something from the nunit.exe program?

Comment: how could i create a log with nunit test.? i have a test via nunit and i want all outputs to be wrriten to a log file